# How do I return a json from a function?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I'm messing around with Javascript, node js, and sails right now. I'm trying to learn how to do some stuff.

Right now, I've got an analogue for a basic situation I want to do. I want to return a json returned from a rest call to a controller, and display it on the webpage.

So far, this is what I have:

```
module.exports = {


  /**
   * `PersonController.scream()`
   */
  scream: function (req, res) {
    function subscream(){
        var per = {voice: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'};
        return per;
    }
    var loudness = subscream()
    return loudness;
  }

};
```

The console.log statement does print the json to the console, but the function never seems to return. I know I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know enough about Javascript or node js to know what to call this problem, so I can't Google it yet unfortunately.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return?

Comment: Because it's not displayed on the page that I use to call the function. I go to `localhost:1337/Person/scream`, and the page never shows me anything.

Comment: @Inglonias Can we see your router code?

Comment: @Li357 What is router code? I haven't written any. I've just set `actions: true,` in my blueprint.js file. (Using sails 1.0)

Comment: Are you sure calling `var scream` like the object `scream` is a good idea?

Comment: @JoDev Not sure. Renaming it doesn't seem to help me, though. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the JSON to the client, you have to send a response and not return the JSON in the function.

```
scream: function (req, res) {
  function subscream(){
    var per = {voice: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'};
    var perString = JSON.stringify(per);
    console.log(perString)
    return perString;
  }
  var loudness = subscream()
  res.send(loudness);
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Will mark this answer correct as soon as I can.
The trouble was that I had no idea `res.send` was even an option. Where can I find some more documentation to that effect?

Comment: Have a look at the Node.js documentation. Here's the link to the LTS version: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: Not sure which documentation for Sails you're looking at, but it's pretty hard to miss in the [controllers docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/controllers#?actions)...

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * `PersonController.scream()`
   */
  scream: function (req, res) {
   function subscream(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     var per = {voice: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'};
        var perString = JSON.stringify(per);
        console.log(perString)
        resolve(perString);
    })
   }
    var scream = subscream()
    scream.then(function(resolvedPromise){
      res.send(resolvedPromise)
    }).catch(function(){
        res.send("error")
     })
  }
};
```